# How to get content of iframe using GWT Query?

Tags: java, gwt, iframe, gwtquery

I trying to do like this:

```
$("iframe.cke_dialog_ui_input_file").contents()
```

but it returns:

```
< #document(gquery, error getting the element string representation: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplMozilla::toString(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;)([JavaScript object(8570)]): doc is null)/>
```

But document is not null!

Help me please to solve this problem :(

**UPD.** HTML CODE:

```
<iframe id="cke_107_fileInput" class="cke_dialog_ui_input_file" frameborder="0" src="javascript:void(0)" title="Upload Image" role="presentation" allowtransparency="0">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden; background: transparent;">
<form lang="en" action="gui/ckeditor/FileUploadServlet?CKEditor=gwt-uid-7&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en" dir="ltr" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label id="cke_106_label" style="display:none" for="cke_107_fileInput_input">Upload Image</label>
<input id="cke_107_fileInput_input" type="file" size="38" name="upload" aria-labelledby="cke_106_label">
</form>
<script>
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(90);window.onbeforeunload = function() {window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(91)}
</script>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Are you using UiBinder? If so you can't access the elements until they are rendered in the view. Otherwise you have to use @UiField IFrameElement iFrameElement. And then use $(iFrameElement).contents(). I ran into this exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contents()` method returns the `HTMLDocument`, so normally you have to find the `<body>` to manipulate it.

```
$("iframe.cke_dialog_ui_input_file").contents().find("body");
```

A common mistake is to query the iframe before it has been fully loaded, so code a delay using a `Timer`, `Scheduler` or `GQuery.delay()`. For instance:

```
$("iframe.cke_dialog_ui_input_file")
  .delay(100, 
    lazy()
      .contents().find("body")
        .css("font-name", "verdana")
        .css("font-size", "x-small")
    .done());
```

Answer (score 2):

**First get the iframe element using javascript like your existing cod and store it into Iframe of GWT**

```
IFrameElement iframe = (IFrameElement) element;
```

**Now use iframe to get content**

```
iframe.getContentDocument().getBody().getInnerText();
```

Hope it help you to get values.